# Unexpected result using ++ operation of C++

Tags: c++

Good day guys, I'm a beginner of c++ and trying various approaches.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int num = 0;
    while (num < 100) {
        cout << num << "\t" << num * num << "\n";
        num++;
    }
}
```

This code prints numbers and square numbers of these, as you know. And I wanted a minimalized version, so I tried it.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int num = 0;
    while (num < 100) cout << num << "\t" << num * num++ << "\n";
}
```

But it prints

```
++n     n^2
```

unexpected.
Why it results like this, and how to simplify it using the ++ operator properly? Thanks for reading.

Comment: This is undefined behavior.

Comment: You have UB. `num * num++` is not properly defined. Also the operations on `cout << num << num++;` is considered UB prior to C++17 as order of the operations wasn't defined.

Comment: Your non-minimalized version is clean, tidy, readable, and above all, correct. Why change it?

Comment: Change `while (num < 100)` to `for (int num = 0; num < 100; ++num)` and put the increment there.

Comment: consider that code is written once but read many times. Hence trying to be too clever almost never pays off on the long run.